# I need to learn how to get back to the main menu in case 6, it confirms to exit but I'm not sure how it can loop back to the menu

Tags: java

Once the user inputs 6, they are shown two choices, to exit the program or go back to the main menu. since I can't use return choice, I don't know any other way to go back to the menu

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte choice = 0;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"This program performs various 
                    computations." +
                    "\n You will be shown a menu from which" +
                    "\n you can choose the operations that will be 
                     performed. " +
                    "\n\n Please click on OK to continue", "Introduction",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    while (choice != 6){
        choice = Byte.parseByte(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "              
                 MAIN MENU\n" +
                "1. Routines for Triangles\n" +
                "2. Routines for Temperatures\n" +
                "3. Routines for Geometric Figures\n" +
                "4. String Manipulations\n" +
                "5. Miscellaneous Simple Games.\n" +
                "6. Quit", "Input",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
        switch (choice){
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                Object[] quit = {"Yes, exit the program", "No, bring me back 
                to the menu"};
                int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Are you sure 
                you want to exit?",

   "Choice",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,null, 
    quit, quit[0]);
                if (option == 0){
                    System.exit(0);
                } //<-- needs to loop back to menu
                break;
            }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *while* its evaluating this:

```
while (choice != 6){}
```

When you get your switch in case 6 the while will no longer execute.

You could change the value of choise if the user decides not to exit the program.

```
if(option !=0){choice=7; break;}
```